# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Tags: wpf, xaml, multithreading, facebook

I am using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Facebook_API.aspx

I am trying to call the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) which is created using [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). But it gives me an error:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

I don't know what to do. I am trying to do this:

```cs
FacebookApplication.FacebookFriendsList ffl = new FacebookFriendsList();
```

But it is giving me that error.

I added a background worker:

```cs
static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync("Message to worker");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // This is called on the worker thread
    FacebookApplication.FacebookFriendsList ffl = new FacebookFriendsList();

    Console.WriteLine(e.Argument);        // Writes "Message to worker"

    // Perform time-consuming task...
}
```

Answer (score 326):

Try to invoke your code from the [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591593%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate{
      // your code
});
```

Comment: This is the *real* answer. You can hack away at WPF's window stupidity with this.

Comment: And similar to this, if you happen to be using MVVMLight you can use `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(Action action)`

Comment: @Andrew It is not stupidity, you're simply trying to access to UI thread from a background thread.

Comment: If you have background sound playing or UI animation going, will STA threads actually not interfere?  Seems odd the OP wanted a background thread (which defaults to MTA) but an STA is acceptable...

Answer (score 163):

If you make the call from the main thread, you must add the STAThread attribute to the Main method, as stated in the previous answer.

If you use a separate thread, it needs to be in a STA (single-threaded apartment), which is not the case for background worker threads. You have to create the thread yourself, like this:

```cs
Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

t.Start();
```

with ThreadProc being a delegate of type ThreadStart.

Comment: can this (using STA) possible have side effect?

Comment: The main side-effect of being STA is that simultaneous COM callbacks are serialized. If you are not using COM callbacks, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Saved my life! Was able to use this in a WPF app that hosted a local API for an integration between two different apps!

Answer (score 31):

You can also try this

```cs
// create a thread  
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>  
{  
    // create and show the window
    FaxImageLoad obj = new FaxImageLoad(destination);  
    obj.Show();  
    
    // start the Dispatcher processing  
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();  
}));  

// set the apartment state  
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  

// make the thread a background thread  
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;  

// start the thread  
newWindowThread.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help when using Applicationcontext class instead of Form.

Comment: I am opening a new form when a button is clicked like I do in numerous other places. Any idea why only one of those places is throwing this error?

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for my particular use case!

Answer (score 21):

I suspect that you are getting a callback to a UI component from a background thread. I recommend that you make that call using a BackgroundWorker as this is UI thread aware.

For the BackgroundWorker, the main program should be marked as [STAThread].

Comment: I tried adding it, as above, but it still gives me the error :/

Comment: I'm not familliar with the code. Can you debug through and find out exactly the line of code causing this?

Answer (score 13):

Just mark your program Main method with the `[STAThread]` attribute and the error goes away! it's magic :)

Example:

```
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    // My code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that using the [STAThread] tag doesn't appear to work in an async context, and what made the difference for me was changing the calling method to have the STAThread tag and also be non async

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I wanted to launch a WPF window from a console app. Simply setting the Main method with `[STAThread]` didn't work.

A combination of Timores' and Mohammad's answer worked for me:

```
private static void StaThreadWrapper(Action action)
{
    var t = new Thread(o =>
    {
        action();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

Example usage:

```
StaThreadWrapper(() =>
{
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();
});
```

Comment: how is this not the answer? Thanks

Comment: I called App.Run() from the callback, and Dispatcher.Run() gave me an exception because the Dispatcher was disposed during action() when I closed the window. I now have `var t = new Thread(o => action());` and .Net gives no complaints.

Answer (score 3):

If the **Application.Current** is **null** for example by unit test, you can try this:

```cs
 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke( YOUR action )
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this error occurred because of a null parameter being passed.  Checking the variable values fixed my issue without having to change the code. I used BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Another situation if you may meet, choosing which Window to **new** and **show**.
Don't make the choice in App.xaml.cs' App() or OnStartup(), instead, make the choice in Startup event.

```cs
// App.xaml.cs
        private App()
        {
            Window window = CheckSession() ? new InstallWindow() : (Window)new LoginWindow();
            window.Show(); // bad 1
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = CheckSession() ? new InstallWindow() : (Window)new LoginWindow();
            window.Show(); // bad 2

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

Below should be good

```cs
// App.xaml.cs
        private App()
        {
            Startup += Application_Startup;
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = CheckSession() ? new InstallWindow() : (Window)new LoginWindow();
            window.Show();  // good
        }
```

Also remember to remove the StartupUri from App.xaml

```xml
<!--App.xaml-->
<Application StartupUri="MainWindow">
<!--remove StartupUri-->
</Application>
```

**OR** add the event here is OK too.

```xml
<!--App.xaml-->
<Application Startup="Application_Startup">

</Application>
```

```cs
// App.xaml.cs
        private App()
        {
            
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = CheckSession() ? new InstallWindow() : (Window)new LoginWindow();
            window.Show();  // good
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you call a new window UI statement in an existing thread, it throws an error. Instead of that create a new thread inside the main thread and write the window UI statement in the new child thread.

Comment: how to write pls explain ?