# "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" error when creating a WPF pop-up Window in thread

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a WPF application in which a thread checks some value. In certain cases, I show a pop-up `Window` in order to display a message. When I create this pop-up window in the thread, an exception is thrown by the pop-up window's constructor:

> *"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."*

How do I resolve this error?

This is my code for creating the pop-up window:

```
// using System.Threading;
// using System.Windows.Threading;
Thread Messagethread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
{
    DispatcherOperation DispacherOP = 
        frmMassenger.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(delegate()
            {
                frmMassenger.Show();
            }));
}));
Messagethread.Start();
```

Comment: I found Problem Root. I have a timer which in the each timer.tick , check for new message`s and then show each new message. Timer thread make my work so hard.

Comment: Off-topic: In WPF, windows are called just that: "windows"; not "forms". That latter term is used in another UI framework, Windows Forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely *`Dispatcher`* is only way to do something (in specific Thread) when we work with multi-threading in WPF!

But for work with Dispatcher we must know 2 things:

1. Too many way to use Dispatcher like Dispatcher_Operation ,
   [window.dispatcher] or etc.
2. We must *`call dispatcher in the main thread of app`* (that thread is must be STA thread)

**So for example:** if we want show other ***window[wpf]*** in another thread, we can use this code:

```
Frmexample frmexample = new Frmexample();
            frmexample .Dispatcher.BeginInvoke //Updated the variable name
                (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() =>
                {
                    frmexample.Show();
                    //---or do any thing you want with that form
                }
                ));
```

**Tip:** `Remember - we can't access any fields or properties from out dispatcher, so use that wisely`

Answer (score 16):

For the thread that you're trying to start the GUI element in, you need to set the apartment state of the thread to STA **BEFORE** you start it.

Example:

```
myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
myThread.Start();
```

Comment: @Rev: Let me know, if it doesn't get past your error let me know the error message and I'll provide the extra info you need.  I think that's all you'll need though.

Comment: thx for help
but that doesn't work.
this problem related to Wpf and Threading.I think We Should use Dispatcher for solving that.
Regards Rev

Comment: @Rev: Probably you have 2 issues.  The threading STA and the dispatcher.  If you want help with the dispatcher let me know and I can show you how.

Comment: I think dispatcher can help me.
;)