# ExcelDna: Async: The calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I'm working with ExcelDna and async functions. If there's an exception in the async:d code I want to show a fancy WPF error window. My problem is that I'm getting the error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." How can I solve this?

```
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "", Category = "")]
    public static async Task<object> /*string*/ Foo(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
                throw new Exception("BOO");
                return "HelloWorld";
            }, ct2.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ShowWpfErrorWindowThatRequiresSTA(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" error when creating a WPF pop-up Window in thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657212/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-error)

Comment: You must display a window on the UI thread.  Use Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183622/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Excel function runs there is no `SynchronizationContext.Current` installed, so the async/await mechanism will runs the code after `await` (including your catch handler) on a ThreadPool thread. That's not a context where you can directly show your WPF form.

Installing a DispatcherSynchronizationContext corresponding to a Dispatcher running on the main thread (or another thread) would work, but you have to do that for every UDF call. Somehow the native code path through Excel loses the .NET call context on the main thread, so the SynchronizationContext gets lost.

Better is probably to assume that the catch handler is running on a ThreadPool thread, and make a `SynchronizationContext.Post` call from the catch handler to take you back to the main thread running your Dispatcher and WPF form.

You can look at how Excel-DNA implements the (WinForms) LogDisplay window. (https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Source/ExcelDna.Integration/LogDisplay.cs). You can call `LogDisplay.WriteLine(...)` from any thread, and it will do a `_syncContext.Post` to run the 'Show' on the main thread.

The C# async/await mechanism works less well with Excel since the native/managed transitions, and whatever Excel does internally, messes up the thread context that needs to flow between continuations. Even on the .NET side, it's not clear how thread context is managed between AppDomains (different Excel add-ins). So it's best not to rely on the .NET runtime being able to thread any kind of context through the managed/native transitions.

Comment: Works! I create a static WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext (seems to work for WPF as well?) in my AutoOpen that I use internally in HandleError.

Comment: How do you mean it won't stick around? How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

Many Office plugins have a problem where `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`, and asynchronous continuations execute on the thread pool. I'd check the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` before the first `await`.

I have had some success in creating a `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` and installing that on the thread before the first `await`. However, installing a WPF context would be more complex.