# Cloud Explorer encounters unexpected error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to attach the debugger to an Azure App Service Web API. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with Azure SDK 2.9.5. The Web API is an ASP.NETCore 1.0.1 app targeting full framework. 
[image]

Comment: lemme find someone here who can help...

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you attach debugging your app, under the App Service node of Server explorer window or the Attach to process window under Debug menu? Whether your code use the Threading components? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657212/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-error

Comment: I attached the debugger using the server explorer. Threading components? What threading component are you referring too?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a bug with how the current tools for Azure App Services (in Azure SDK 2.9.5) call in to the debugger. We've prepared the fix for this and it'll be included in the next Azure SDK release.

For the time being, you can still attach the debugger to the site by using the `Attach to Process...` method.

First, make sure remote debugging is enabled on your site for the version of VS you're running by visiting portal.azure.com, browsing to the site, clicking on `Application Settings` in the flyout, turning the `Remote debugging` setting to `On`, setting `Remote Visual Studio version` appropriately and clicking `Save` at the top of the blade.

[image]

Returning to VS, click `Attach to Process...` on the `Debug` menu.

[image: Attach to process on the debug menu]

On the dialog that pops up, enter the address of your site and port 4020

[image: Attach to process dialog]

If prompted for credentials, you can get them by visiting portal.azure.com, browsing to the site in question and clicking the `Get publish profile` button.

[image]

This will start the download of a `.pubsettings` XML file. In this file, there are two `<publishProfile>` tags - on the one with `publishMethod="FTP"` the values for `userName` and `userPWD` contain the username and password values you'll need.

After you're authenticated, you should see the list of processes running on the site. Generally, you'll want to attach to `w3wp.exe` (or `dotnet.exe` if you're running a .NET Core app).

Comment: For some reason, it's failing to authenticate. I made sure I selected the correct profile, cut & paste the username and userPWD fields, but it just keeps saying "Authentication failed".

Comment: @SteveW. I just ran through this to make sure it worked with a site & noticed that you'll actually need the `FTP` credentials instead of the `MSDeploy` ones. I've updated the answer accordingly. The other time where I ran in to the repetitive Authentication Failed message was when I didn't have the remote debugging settings configured appropriately (location of them is in the first screenshot in my answer, the first button should be `On` and the second should match your VS version). Sorry for the delay.