# WPF + PRISM - Cannot 'LoadModule' in separate thread

Tags: wpf, prism, loadmodule

I have a WPF application in PRISM architecture.

I have a 'Login View' that is shown in the 'Main Region' when the app loads.

When the user presses 'Login' - I connect to a WCF service, authenticate the user, and get a list of roles for that user from the service.

Then - according to the user's roles - I load different modules, using the 'Module Manager'.

Problem is - I want all the work after the 'Login' button is pressed to be done in a separate thread, because it might take time to connect to the service etc, and I don't want the UI to be frozen.

But - if I put the code to 'connect, authenticate, get roles, load modules' in a separate thread - I get an exception when I call '_moduleManager.LoadModule' that says:

**The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.**

How can I solve this ?

I have tried different solutions.
I have tried to set the new thread's 'Apartment State = STA' and it didn't help.
I thought about saving the 'Dispatcher' object in the constructor of the View-Model, and then do 'dispatcher.Invoke' when I call 'LoadModule', but that is bad design (View-Model should not use Dispatcher, and also it is bad for testing).

Any ideas how I can solve this ??

Only the 'LoadModule' gives me grief, all the other stuff works fine.

.

**[Update] - Added Code Sample :**

```
[Export]
public class LoginViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoginViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IModuleManager moduleManager)
    {
        this.LoginCommand   = new DelegateCommand(LoginExecute, LoginCanExecute);
        this._regionManager = regionManager;
        this._moduleManager = moduleManager;
    }

    private void LoginExecute()
    {
        IsBusy = true; // Set this to 'true' so controls go disabled
        LoginStatus = ""; // Clear the 'login status' string


        Thread loginThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoginWork));
        loginThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        loginThread.Start();
    }

    private void LoginWork()
    {
        ParamsToGetRoles param = new ParamsToGetRoles
        {
            Username = Username,
            InputtedPassword = Password
        };

        try
        {
            // Connect to the secure service, and request the user's roles
            _clientSecure = new AuthenticationServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_MyService");
            _clientSecure.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = param.Username;
            _clientSecure.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = param.InputtedPassword;
            _clientSecure.ChannelFactory.Faulted += new EventHandler(ChannelFactory_Faulted);
            var local = _clientSecure.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            _clientSecure.GetRolesCompleted += new EventHandler<GetRolesCompletedEventArgs>(clientSecure_GetRolesCompleted);
            _clientSecure.GetRolesAsync(param);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    void clientSecure_GetRolesCompleted(object sender, GetRolesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            _clientSecure.Close();
            LoginSuccess(e.Result.UserRoles);
        }
        else
        {
            LoginFailure("Unable to authenticate");
        }
        _clientSecure = null;
    }

    private void LoginSuccess(List<UserTypeEnum> rolesOfAuthenticatedUser)
    {
        LoginStatus = "Success";

        if (rolesOfAuthenticatedUser.Contains(UserTypeEnum.Administrator))
        {
            // This is what throws the exception !
            // This is called by the 'EndInvoke' of the 'GetRoles' operation, 
            // Which was called in the 'LoginWork' function which was run on a separate thread !
            _moduleManager.LoadModule(WellKnownModuleNames.ModuleAdmin);
        }

        NavigateToMainMenu();

        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you put the correct thread's state to STA? also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this and many others ask the exact same

Comment: I'd just use the `Dispatcher` to send the LoadModules command to the main UI thread :)

Comment: @Rachel - but isn't using 'Dispatcher' bad for testing purposes ? and also - I thought the 'View-Model' should know nothing about the UI, and if I use the 'Dispatcher' to do something on the UI thread - that beats the purpose a bit, no ?

Comment: @stijn - I am sure. I created a new thread just like in the link you have provided, and I set it's apartment state to STA. and inside that thread's function - I try to load the modules and then I get that exception

Comment: can you post the simplest example that fails? I'd like to test this, but my apps don't use LoadModule like that so I need code.. Also, nothing wrong with Dispatcher for testsing: just hide it behind an interface eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.presentation.events.idispatcherfacade.aspx

Comment: @stijn - I have updated my question to include code that should clarify my problem...

Comment: @stijn - maybe the problem is this : even though I spawn a separate thread and set it to 'STA', in this thread I call an ASYNC operation on a WCF client - so MAYBE when the call returns ("end invoke") and I try to do 'LoadModule' - this no longer is on the spawned 'STA' thread ? maybe that is the problem ?

Comment: lol you beat me to it,, that's just what I started to type out in detail :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach the debugger and inspect the threads window with a breakpoint set at `clientSecure_GetRolesCompleted`. I'm pretty sure it is not being called from the loginThread: while `LoginWork` does run in the loginThread, it then adds an eventhandler to the completion event of an async operation. Async = runs in yet another thread.

So what probably happens:

- `LoginExecute` executes in the UI thread
- starts a seperate thread B to run `LoginWork`
- calls `GetRolesAsync` so start a thread C (which is *not* STA) to get the roles
- thread C eventually calls 'clientSecure_GetRolesCompleted', not thread B

So, you do not need a seperate thread for `LoginWork` since the actual work is already done as an async operation. To get around the loading issue, either try to make the 'get roles' thread STA, or better, use a dispatcher so `LoginSuccess` gets invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Excellent way to put it. Dispatcher works. Just to clarify - I do need a separate thread for 'LoginWork' because connecting to the WCF service might take 1-2 seconds, and I don't want that to hang the UI thread, so that's why I put 'LoginWork' in a different thread.

Comment: That being said - it seems stupid now to use the 'ASYNC' mode of calling, since it is not done on the UI thread anyway.
So I might as well just call the SYNC operation and when it finished marshal the 'LoadModule' via the dispatcher...

Comment: in that case, yes, that's the best option.