# How to open any view in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker

In my desktop application i want to open view in BackgroundWorker  to show reminder.
but when i try to open view it gives me the following error.
**"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."**
and stackTrace is

```
 at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Window..ctor()
   at MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow..ctor()
```

can anyone have solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in this manner:

```
    private BackgroundWorker _BgWorker;


    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _BgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _BgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        _BgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ///your code to get the data from database...
    }

void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      //you code to open a view
    }
```

Use this in the Runworker completed

```
Thread Messagethread = new Thread(
        new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            DispatcherOperation DispacherOP = frmMassenger.Dispatcher
                .BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        frmMassenger.Show();
                    }
            ));
        } ));
        Messagethread.Start();
```

later you join the Thread with main thread using:

```
Thread.join(userthread);
```

Hope This will help you.

Comment: It only works to open view one time.As i am using timer to run background worker after 20 sec it gives me same error @Krish

Comment: it gives me Exception of NullRefernce at frmMassenger.Dispatcher and i can create instance of my view as my main exception occurs..@Krish

Comment: It works after replacing frmMassenger.Dispatcher to Dispatcher and i can open view as per timers interval. Thanx for help