# WPF inside winforms UI error - The calling Thread must be STA

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, winforms

I have a simple WPF form, built as a dll file.

I have a winforms application.

In my `MainForm.cs` constructor, I load `Form2.cs` (which contains the ElementHost that calls the dll) to  `PanelTest` in `MainForm.cs`

When I build, i get this:

```
The calling Thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

in the:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.elementHost3d = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();

}
```

of my `Form2.Designer.cs`

Relevant code is:

Program.cs

```
public Program()
        {

            _formLauncher = new MainForm();

            // Launch main UI as unique thread.
            ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(InitUILauncher);
            Thread tInitUILauncher = new Thread(ts);
            tInitUILauncher.Start();


        }

        [STAThread]
        protected void InitUILauncher()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(_formLauncher);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
        }
```

MainForm.cs

```
   public MainForm()
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                InitPanels();
            }
    private void InitPanels()
            {
                PanelTest.Controls.Clear();
                var Form2Var= new Form2();
                PanelTest.Controls.Add(Form2Var);

               }

    }
```

Form2.cs

```
public Form2()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate {

                WPFUserControl.UserControl1 control = new WPFUserControl.UserControl1();
                elementHost3d.Child = control;

            });

        }
```

I added the delagate code from here:

[The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this)

But I see the same issue. Reading around, I think I need to add an `[STAThread]`

somewhere, is this right? Where should it be?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread?

Comment: Which? Do you mean in Program? Should I launch the MainForm from the main function instead?

Comment: Just use the standard WinForms boilerplate main method. I don't see why you've changed it to create a new thread.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change to the usual method, and it broke some code further in the application.(This is a legacy project, from multiple programmers)  Is there a way to adjust the code above to work? Or do i need to delve into a larger re-write?

Comment: If you fix the code above to solve the initial STA problem, you'll probably have the same problems you've found since. To make your 'new' thread STA, you need to call `tInitUILauncher.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` before you start it.