# Wpf Error when trying to add button to WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a FileSystemWatcher that checks a folder for changes, of course. So when you add a file to the folder I need to add a button to a wrappanel. I have tried:

```
    public void CheckDir()
{
    string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    var folderName = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}games";

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = folderName,

        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
    };

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

}

//When button is changed, created, or deleted
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.Name + " " + e.ChangeType);

    var buttonName = "Button_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath).Replace(" ", "");

    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        var buttonContent = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);

        CreateButton(buttonContent, buttonName);
    }
    else if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {

        buttonHolder.Children.Remove(btnFile);
    }
}
```

And the CreateButton void:

```
private void CreateButton(string buttonContent, string buttonName)
{
    Button newBtn = new Button
    {
        Content = buttonContent,
        Name = buttonName,
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
        Width = 260,
        Height = 100
    };

    newBtn.Click += OpenFile;

    buttonHolder.Children.Add(newBtn);
}
```

But I get an error when trying to add the button:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

And I have no idea what to change or what the error means, and yes, I've searched for it, but could not find a solution or good explanation to what it is.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2329978/9145461) help?

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't understand it, but that link helped me. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess someone else could explain the backgrounds far better than I could.

Comment: Quanik helped me out with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this)

Comment: Just for fun, try this: place a breakpoint on the line `var folderName = $"[snip]"` and another on a line inside of the event handler `OnChanged` - when the breakpoints are hit are you inside the same thread? You won't be - so make sure you marshal your update back on to the UI thread (which is likely to be the thread your first breakpoint was set on). Better still, think about using a ListControl bound to the same observable list of filenames, and the item template in the ListControl will be a Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain this exception to you.

First, I try to explain what a background thread and a UI thread is and their difference, and then my 2 simple rules to follow when dealing with this exception.

**My explanation on STA and MTA, UI thread and background threads**

`STA` stands for `Single Thread Apartment`, and it has a counterpart called `Multi Thread Apartment (MTA)`. And their differences are discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta), and you can use `STA vs. MTA` as keywords for your Google searching if you are interested. You might be confused when you see terms like "STAThreadAttribute"/ "COM" / "CoInitializeEx" in your search, don't worry, because you are not alone, they are some crazy old technologies that few people need to work with.

And a thread uses one of these models, `STA` or `MTA`. You might have noticed that some code like

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
```

This means that the thread is using `STA`. In WPF, the main thread is using `STA`, the controls are created on this thread, and events handlers like `Button_Click` are also executed on this thread, let's called this *the UI thread*.

And the *background threads* you started by using classes like `Thread/ThreadPool/Task` are using `MTA` by default, this is also the case for event handler of `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed`, and, as in this case, the event handler of `FileSystemWatcher` events.

By now you have the idea that your code either runs on *UI thread (STA)* or one of the *background threads (MTA)*.

**My Simple Rules**

1. Normally, you need to create controls on the *UI thread*. (I don't discuss alternative solution of "creating on background thread and making it freezable" here, just to keep the rules simple to follow. And as pointed out in the comment by @slugster, you can create a control on *any* thread, but you can only access it from the same thread where it was created.)
2. From a *background thread*, if you want to access controls, you need to marshal you code to the UI thread by using `Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke` - so the code will be executed on the UI thread. Otherwise, you get this exception (`The calling thread must be STA...`).

Comment: All due respect but this isn't so much a STA vs MTA argument, the error message is a little misleading. In WPF you can create controls on any thread, and you can have more than one UI thread - the trick is to only update the control from the thread it was created on (so your rule #2 is the key one).

Comment: Welcome the clarification. Yes, that is more accurate. I use the term “UI thread” loosely, and heard that there are more than one UI thread (for rendering in parallel?) but haven’t found myself in a situation to deal with that so far.