# Task.Delay(N) System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanted to open a new `WPF window` from my `MainWindow's ViewModel` with a 2 second delay by doing the following:

```
await Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ =>
                    {
                        Restart wndRestart = new Restart();
                        wndRestart.Show();
                    }
                );
```

Sadly, I am constantly getting: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'`

I actually looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this), but I was unable to use `[STAThread]` even after refactoring a method.

Comment: Voting to reopen, as the linked answer doesn't really address _this_ particular problem and the required solution/workaround.

Comment: _"the linked answer doesn't really address this particular problem"_ -- sure it does. Or at least, it addresses _an example of this vaguely stated problem_. The fact is, there's not enough detail in the question to know what's wrong. If the code posted were executed in the UI thread in the first place, the exception wouldn't happen at all. So one way to fix it is to execute it in the UI thread, per the duplicate. There are lots of other scenarios that could result in the exception, but there's zero evidence in the question any of those apply.

Comment: Don't use `Task.ContinueWith`. Simply continue with your code after the `await`.

Comment: Only to clarify this: a `Window` can only be created on a UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own synchronization context to `ContinueWith` to tell the task scheduler where your continuation should run:

```
await Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ =>
                {
                    Restart wndRestart = new Restart();
                    wndRestart.Show();
                },
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
            );
```

Otherwise you'll get a thread-pool thread that most likely isn't STA.

However, for a one-shot in WPF to perform some action after a delay, it's perfectly fine to just use a `DispatcherTimer` as well.

Comment: Or simply do not use `Task.ContinueWith` in this context. Since you await `Task.Delay` and the `Task` is configured with `ConfigureAwait(true)` by default, the execution would continue on the proper thread (UI thread).

Comment: That's an option, if targeting .NET 4.5 and later, yes. I've once stumbled over the very same problem, just tied to .NET 4.0 ...

Comment: Basically your are right, but `Task.Delay` wasn't available in .NET 4.0. `await` was also not available in this version. This means the questions targets .NET >= 4.5. There is no sense to continue execution after a simple `await` using `Task.ContinueWith`, except you want to execute the continuation on a worker thread - which is clearly not the case in the OP's scenario. So it appears to be wiser to drop the overhead of configuring the continuation's thread pool thread. Note that `Task.Delay` is a pure asynchronous method, that doesn't run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Good point. Agreed :-)